# Maven Build Failure for a project

Tags: maven

I download a project and run `mvn clean package`, then it downloads files automatically but builds failure. It's my first time to use Maven. I searched the error log at Internet but still have no idea about how to deal with it. Please help me, I appreciate it.

```
Running cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.ChineseToPinYinFunctionsTest

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.HashFunctionsTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 sec

Results :

Failed tests:   testGetIdCardProvince(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.strin
g.ChinaIdCardFunctionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[å??äº¬å??]>
  testGetIdCardArea(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.ChinaIdCardFunct
ionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[ä??å??å?º]>
  testGetIdCardCity(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.ChinaIdCardFunct
ionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[å??äº¬å??]>

Tests run: 41, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.916 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-21T12:13:16-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project presto-third-functions: There are test failu
res.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Z\Desktop\s\PrestoFunctions\target\surefire-rep
orts for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on proj
ect presto-third-functions: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\Z\Desktop\s\PrestoFunctions\target\surefire-reports for
 the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures
.

Please refer to C:\Users\Z\Desktop\s\PrestoFunctions\target\surefire-reports for
 the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution (Surefire
Helper.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary (SurefirePlu
gin.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary (SurefirePl
ugin.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPrecond
itionsChecked (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSu
refireMojo.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBui
ldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.jav
a:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessor
Impl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launche
r.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:2
29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launc
her.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356
)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

I also enter the link given by [Help 1], but still get nothing.

I find some questions on stackoverflow, lots of answers say if there has pom will be better, so I post it.

Thanks in advance!

```
-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>cc.shanruifeng</groupId>

<artifactId>presto-third-functions</artifactId>

<version>0.5.1</version>


-<properties>

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

<project.build.targetJdk>1.8</project.build.targetJdk>

<project.report.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.outputEncoding>

<project.report.inputEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.inputEncoding>

<presto.version>0.167</presto.version>

<guava.version>20.0</guava.version>

<joda.version>2.8.2</joda.version>

<airlift.version>0.139</airlift.version>

<pinyin4j.version>2.5.0</pinyin4j.version>

<commons-codec.version>1.10</commons-codec.version>

<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

<org.slf4j.version>1.7.12</org.slf4j.version>

</properties>


-<dependencyManagement>


-<dependencies>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>

<artifactId>presto-spi</artifactId>

<version>${presto.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>

<artifactId>presto-main</artifactId>

<version>${presto.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>

<artifactId>guava</artifactId>

<version>${guava.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>joda-time</groupId>

<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>

<version>${joda.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>io.airlift</groupId>

<artifactId>json</artifactId>

<version>${airlift.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.belerweb</groupId>

<artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>

<version>${pinyin4j.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>

<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>

<version>${commons-codec.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>junit</groupId>

<artifactId>junit</artifactId>

<version>${junit.version}</version>

</dependency>

<!-- Logger -->



-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

<version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>

<version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>

<version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>


-<dependencies>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>

<artifactId>presto-spi</artifactId>

<scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>

<artifactId>presto-main</artifactId>

<scope>test</scope>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>

<artifactId>annotations</artifactId>

<version>2.0.3</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>

<artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>

<version>6.5.9</version>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>

<artifactId>guava</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>joda-time</groupId>

<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>io.airlift</groupId>

<artifactId>json</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>com.belerweb</groupId>

<artifactId>pinyin4j</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>

<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>junit</groupId>

<artifactId>junit</artifactId>

<scope>test</scope>

</dependency>

<!-- Logger -->



-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>

</dependency>


-<dependency>

<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

<artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>

</dependency>

</dependencies>


-<build>

<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>


-<plugins>


-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.4.3</version>


-<executions>


-<execution>

<phase>package</phase>


-<goals>

<goal>shade</goal>

</goals>


-<configuration>


-<artifactSet>


-<excludes>

<exclude/>

</excludes>

</artifactSet>

<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>

</configuration>

</execution>

</executions>

</plugin>

<!-- Tweak the compiler to use more memory and use UTF-8 for the source code. -->



-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

<version>3.1</version>


-<configuration>

<source>${project.build.targetJdk}</source>

<target>${project.build.targetJdk}</target>

<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>

<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>

</configuration>

</plugin>

<!-- Resource plugins should always use UTF-8 -->



-<plugin>

<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>

<version>2.6</version>


-<configuration>

<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>

</configuration>

</plugin>

</plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your tests are failing?

Answer (score 1):

The link given by [Help 1] is just a general information about build failure.
You have to read previous information from log. So..

1. First of all your tests are failing

   > Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are
   >   test failures
2. A little bit higher in log you will find more detailed information (3 tests are failing, you have even information about what assertion not passed - expected ... but was ...):

   > Failed tests:
   >   testGetIdCardProvince(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.strin
   >   g.ChinaIdCardFunctionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[å??äº¬å??]>
   >   testGetIdCardArea(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.ChinaIdCardFunct
   >   ionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[ä??å??å?º]>
   >   testGetIdCardCity(cc.shanruifeng.functions.udfs.scalar.string.ChinaIdCardFunct
   >   ionsTest): expected:<[???]> but was:<[å??äº¬å??]>
   >
   > Tests run: 41, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

When you fix your tests everything gonna be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests are failing you have an option to skip test if that's what you want:

```
 mvn clean compile install -DskipTests
```